# Asynchronous Calls (specifically iOS geocoding)

Tags: iphone, ios, asynchronous, geocoding

I'm wondering how to deal with this particular issue:

I'm creating a place object, which gets initialized with a geographical lat-long pair. Then I use the iOS geocoder to get an address for that coordinate. I want to set that address to one of my instance variables. However, this asynchronous call doesn't get completed in time, so when I instantiate my object and try to display the address, it hasn't been done yet. What are some strategies to deal with this and similar problems?

Thanks! Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I don't feel like creating an extensive answer on Christmas Eve so I'll give a brief answer here for now, and edit it later if you've got questions and/or want more details.*

Asynchronous requests all have delegate/protocol methods that let you know when the request has failed or succeeded. You should use the NSNotification API and register any object that needs the address for a notification that's triggered when the object completes the request. When the object receives the notification, it can then configure its views or whatever it needs to do. In the requestDidFinish (or whatever) method, you should send the notification.

Check out this article for details (as well as some cool stuff about threading!): http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Comment: You're welcome! I just started reading up on iOS multithreading etc and came across this article a few days ago, so this was good timing. Very cool stuff.